# ansible raises an error when a task with regex is executed by "jenkins" user

Tags: linux, jenkins, ansible

Ansible task fails when the playbook is run by "jenkins" on my Ubuntu.
The same playbook can be run w/o any issues by an admin user. 
Any idea why this happens and how to fix it?

This is the task:

```
- name: compare vlan/port mappings against the vlan_db
  set_fact:
    fact1: "{{ item.1.vlan_id }}"
    fact2: "{{ item.0.name }}"
    fact3: "{{ item.1.sap[inventory_hostname] | join('.*')}}"
  when: "inventory_hostname in item.1.sap"
  failed_when: not vlan_db.stdout_lines is regex(fact1 + '.*' + fact2 + '.*' + fact3)
  with_subelements:
    - "{{ customers }}"
    - service
```

This is the error:

```
fatal: [leaf-1]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "The conditional check 'not vlan_db.stdout_lines is regex(fact1 + '.*' + fact2 + '.*' + fact3)' failed. The error was: Unexpected templating type err                                                or occurred on ({% if not vlan_db.stdout_lines is regex(fact1 + '.*' + fact2 + '.*' + fact3) %} True {% else %} False {% endif %}): expected string or buffer"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is quite clear:

```
Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({% if not vlan_db.stdout_lines is regex(fact1 + '.*' + fact2 + '.*' + fact3) %} True {% else %} False {% endif %}): expected string or buffer
```

because `stdout_lines` is a `list(str)` and not `str`; what you wanted is either:

`vlan_db.stdout is regex(fact1 + '.*' + fact2 ... etc)`

if you intended to match the entirety of the output, or

`vlan_db.stdout_lines | select("regex", fact1+'.*'+fact2...etc) | list`

if your regex should only match one (or more) of the individual lines

Answer (score 0):

*mdaniel* probably you did not read the question and drew an immediate conclusion. Playbook is fine and working perfect when run by another user. Problem appears only when „jenkins“ user executes it.

```
**jenkins**@vagrant:~/workspace/NetLab_jenkinsbranch$  ansible-playbook -i Step4-CICD/hosts Step4-CICD/integration_tests/vlan_test.yml

PLAY [leaf] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [collect the vlan database] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [leaf-1]
changed: [leaf-2]

TASK [compare vlan/port mappings against the vlan_db] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [leaf-1]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'not vlan_db.stdout_lines is regex(fact1 + '.*' + fact2 + '.*' + fact3)' failed. The error was: Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({% if not vlan_db.stdout_lines is regex(fact1 + '.*' + fact2 + '.*' + fact3) %} True {% else %} False {% endif %}): expected string or buffer"}
fatal: [leaf-2]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'not vlan_db.stdout_lines is regex(fact1 + '.*' + fact2 + '.*' + fact3)' failed. The error was: Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({% if not vlan_db.stdout_lines is regex(fact1 + '.*' + fact2 + '.*' + fact3) %} True {% else %} False {% endif %}): expected string or buffer"}

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
leaf-1                     : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
leaf-2                     : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

jenkins@vagrant:~/workspace/NetLab_jenkinsbranch$ su vagrant
Password:
**vagrant**@vagrant:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/NetLab_jenkinsbranch$ ansible-playbook -i Step4-CICD/hosts Step4-CICD/integration_tests/vlan_test.yml

PLAY [leaf] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [collect the vlan database] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [leaf-1]
changed: [leaf-2]

TASK [compare vlan/port mappings against the vlan_db] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [leaf-1] => (item=[{u'name': u'cust-1', u'l3_vni': u'101'}, {u'gw': u'10.0.0.254/24', u'sap': {u'leaf-1': [u'Et3'], u'leaf-2': [u'Et3']}, u'vni': u'1010', u'vlan_id': u'10'}])
ok: [leaf-2] => (item=[{u'name': u'cust-1', u'l3_vni': u'101'}, {u'gw': u'10.0.0.254/24', u'sap': {u'leaf-1': [u'Et3'], u'leaf-2': [u'Et3']}, u'vni': u'1010', u'vlan_id': u'10'}])
ok: [leaf-1] => (item=[{u'name': u'cust-1', u'l3_vni': u'101'}, {u'gw': u'10.0.1.254/24', u'sap': {u'leaf-1': [u'Et3'], u'leaf-2': [u'Et3']}, u'vni': u'1011', u'vlan_id': u'11'}])
ok: [leaf-2] => (item=[{u'name': u'cust-1', u'l3_vni': u'101'}, {u'gw': u'10.0.1.254/24', u'sap': {u'leaf-1': [u'Et3'], u'leaf-2': [u'Et3']}, u'vni': u'1011', u'vlan_id': u'11'}])
skipping: [leaf-1] => (item=[{u'name': u'cust-2', u'l3_vni': u'102'}, {u'gw': u'20.0.0.254/24', u'sap': {u'leaf-3': [u'Et3', u'Et4'], u'leaf-4': [u'Et3']}, u'vni': u'1020', u'vlan_id': u'20'}])
skipping: [leaf-2] => (item=[{u'name': u'cust-2', u'l3_vni': u'102'}, {u'gw': u'20.0.0.254/24', u'sap': {u'leaf-3': [u'Et3', u'Et4'], u'leaf-4': [u'Et3']}, u'vni': u'1020', u'vlan_id': u'20'}])
skipping: [leaf-1] => (item=[{u'name': u'cust-2', u'l3_vni': u'102'}, {u'gw': u'20.0.1.254/24', u'sap': {u'leaf-3': [u'Et3'], u'leaf-4': [u'Et3']}, u'vni': u'1021', u'vlan_id': u'21'}])
skipping: [leaf-2] => (item=[{u'name': u'cust-2', u'l3_vni': u'102'}, {u'gw': u'20.0.1.254/24', u'sap': {u'leaf-3': [u'Et3'], u'leaf-4': [u'Et3']}, u'vni': u'1021', u'vlan_id': u'21'}])

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
leaf-1                     : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
leaf-2                     : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

vagrant@vagrant:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/NetLab_jenkinsbranch$
```